# Intercepting and modifying specific packets (IPv4/TCP)

Tags: java, tcp, packets

I'm trying to intercept packets and be able to block them from incoming/outgoing, for a specific domain

In order to do that i made my (java) program adds the domain to the hosts file with a redirection to my own public ipv4 adress (this doesnt matter it just can't be the real IP and i must be able to intercept it, redirecting to my own IP makes sure nobody else in the world receives it). Secondly, i make the program listen to that signal and resend it on a different source port to the real server. (Checksum changes have been taken care of) Now the plan is to receive the response and do the exact same thing, but now by editting the source ip (my own public IP in this case) and the destination port

This should create a program where i'm a kind of middle men between a connection

But it doesnt work as expected, the moment im getting a response of the server (flags SYN/ACK), it's automatically sending them back a RST flag (IPv4/TCP) from the random chosen port by me which isnt the same as the port of the real client

I don't know if there are better ways to do this (there probably are) and how to prevent the problem I'm having, I couldn't really find similiar things to this on the internet. Any kind of help/hints would be appreciated

Keep in mind that I'm using jnetpscape at this moment and it would be nice to continue at what i'm doing right now

EDIT (code):

this is the "HConnection" class (not fully showed but all essential things):

```
public class HConnection    {

private volatile int state = -1;           // current state of the program
private volatile boolean HostFileEdited = false;
private volatile String domain = null;
private volatile boolean waitingConnection = false;

private volatile String ipOfDomain = null; // string of the server adress
private volatile byte[] ipofdomb;         //4 bytes of the server adress

private volatile String myIpAdr = null;   //my IP adress
private volatile byte[] myIpb;            //my public IP in 4 bytes

private volatile byte[] port = null;      //port of proxy
private volatile byte[] falseport = null; //port of client


private volatile ServerSocket server;

public HConnection()    {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(0);
        byte[] tempPortb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(server.getLocalPort()).array();
        System.out.println(server.getLocalPort());
        port = new byte[]{tempPortb[2], tempPortb[3]};
        (new Thread() {
              public void run() {
                    try {
                        server.accept();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
              }
        }).start();
        state = 0;


    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {System.out.println("fail");} catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("fail");}
}


public String getPublicIP ()    {
    try{

        myIpAdr =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com/").openStream())).readLine();
        System.out.println(myIpAdr);
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName(myIpAdr);
        myIpb = ip.getAddress();
        return myIpAdr;
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
    return null;
}

public void setUrl(String domain)   {
    this.domain = domain;
}

public int getState()   {
    return state;
}

public void prepare()   {
    try{
        URL urlofsite = new URL("https://"+domain);
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(urlofsite.getHost());
        ipOfDomain = address.getHostAddress();
        System.out.println(ipOfDomain);
        ipofdomb = address.getAddress();

        addToHostsFile(getPublicIP() + "\t" + domain);

        state = 1;
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}

public void abort() {

    removeFromHostsFile(domain);
    HostFileEdited = false;

    state = -1;

    try {
        server.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {   }

    waitingConnection = false;
}

public void awaitConnection()   {
    if (state == 1) {
        waitingConnection = true;

        System.out.println("stap1");

        StringBuilder errbuf = new StringBuilder();     // For any error msgs  
        int snaplen = 64 * 1024;           // Capture all packets, no truncation  
        int flags = Pcap.MODE_PROMISCUOUS; // capture all packets  
        int timeout = 0;           // 10 seconds in millis  
        Pcap pcap = Pcap.openLive("wlp4s0", snaplen, flags, timeout, errbuf);  
        if (pcap == null) {  
              System.err.printf("Error while opening device for capture: "  
                    + errbuf.toString());  
              return;  
        }

        PcapHeader hdr = new PcapHeader(JMemory.POINTER);  
        JBuffer buf = new JBuffer(JMemory.POINTER);
        int id = JRegistry.mapDLTToId(pcap.datalink());  

        while (HostFileEdited && waitingConnection && state == 1 && pcap.nextEx(hdr, buf) == Pcap.NEXT_EX_OK)   {

                PcapPacket packet = new PcapPacket(hdr, buf);  

                try {
                    packet.scan(id);
                    TcpPacket pkt = new TcpPacket(packet);
                    if (pkt.isTcp())    {
                        if (pkt.destinationIPequals(myIpAdr) && pkt.getDestinationPort() == 443 && (falseport == null || Arrays.equals(pkt.getSourcePortb(), falseport)))   {
                            if (falseport == null)  {
                                falseport = pkt.getSourcePortb();
                            }

                            pkt.changeDestinationIP(ipofdomb);
                            pkt.changeSourcePort(port);
                            pkt.iPchecksumFix();
                            pkt.tcPchecksumFix();
                            ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.wrap(pkt.getPacketInBytes());

                            System.out.println("10");
                            System.out.println("OUT"+ (pcap.sendPacket(b)));

                        }
                        else if (pkt.sourceIPequals(ipOfDomain) && pkt.getSourcePort() == 443 && falseport != null && Arrays.equals(pkt.getDestinationPortb(),port) )   {

                            pkt.changeSourceIP(myIpb);
                            pkt.changeDestinationPort(falseport);
                            pkt.iPchecksumFix();
                            pkt.tcPchecksumFix();
                            ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.wrap(pkt.getPacketInBytes());

                            System.out.println("IN"+ pcap.sendPacket(b));
                        }

                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e) {}

        }
        System.out.println("stap2");
        if (state == 1 && waitingConnection == true)    state = 2;
        waitingConnection = false;
    }

}
}
```

The "awaitConnection()" method is were currently most things are happening. But this will only be the beginning of my program

HConnection is called from the main class (SWT Designer):

```
private Button btnNewButton_1;
private HConnection connectie;

private void btnConnect_clicked(SelectionEvent e) throws InterruptedException {

    if (btnNewButton_1.getText().equals("Connect")) {
        String Url = combo.getText();
        connectie = new HConnection();
        connectie.setUrl(Url);
        connectie.prepare();

        lblNewLabel_2.setText("Waiting -> client");

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                    connectie.awaitConnection();

                    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            if (connectie.getState() == 2)  {
                                lblNewLabel_2.setText("Replacing URL");
                            }
                            else    {
                                lblNewLabel_2.setText("Failed");
                                connectie.abort();
                                btnNewButton_1.setText("Connect");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    if (connectie.getState() == 2)  {
                        // go on with the rest of the program


                    }
              }
        }).start();

        btnNewButton_1.setText("Abort");
    }
    else if(btnNewButton_1.getText().equals("Abort"))   {
        connectie.abort();

        lblNewLabel_2.setText("Aborted");
        btnNewButton_1.setText("Connect");
    }



}
```

Comment: Sounds like you closed your proxy's socket, so when they send a packet, it's rejected.

Comment: @erickson do you have any idea how I can solve it?

Comment: Will that part be fixed when doing this?:                                                    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(proxy port); 
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();                                                     (can't try at this moment)

Comment: That's not enough code. Post a [mcve].

Comment: @erickson Will do when possible, btw, you Have any idea on what IP i could use (in the hosts file)? My own IP responds to the packets so thats not well

Comment: The hosts file only applies to outbound traffic. I assume you aren't configuring your firewall to reject or drop packets because you want to respond to outbound traffic. So your last comment doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: When a packet is sent to my own IP it responds to it with a RST flag, thats why I asked, could i redirect the incoming packets to anywhere else then my own IP, somewhere it's impossible to response with RST Flags

Comment: Wow, now we are back to the beginning: It probably responds with an RST because the socket that should receive that packet is closed too soon. Nothing is listening on that port anymore so your OS sends an RST. Kind of hard to say without reading the code.

Comment: I understand, I'll update the code when I'm home

Comment: code has been updated @erickson

Answer (score 1):

The following code accepts a connection, but doesn't maintain a reference to the resulting `Socket` instance. This `Socket` is eligible for garbage collection, and when that happens, it is automatically closed. A client sending data to that socket will then receive an RST.

```
public void run() {
  try {
    server.accept();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: Then how do I fix that? I don't see how i'm not maintaining a reference, there is a declared SocketServer "server"? (i'm not saying you're wrong, but i just don't see it). Is there any way to make this work using the code I already have? Also, if you'd like, I'm always open for suggestions to making my program better, I'm not that experienced yet, so just letting me now if something really should be different would be cool.

Comment: @JonasAnon You need to assign the socket to a variable and then, presumably, use it to send and receive data. Something like `Socket socket = server.accept(); InputStream input = socket.getInputStream(); int ch = input.read();`

Comment: Currently packets from myself are being intercepted while going to destination: my own public IP port 443, and they're outgoing using an unused random port to the real server. Shouldn't I make sure these 2 are the same?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible.. this will make a two-direction connection and I'm in no way able to send packets to the real domain. Maybe if i could somehow convert this DataInputStream/InputStream to a PcapPacket (from jnetpcap) and manually adding stuff such as IP adresses, checksums, ethernet,ipv4,TCP header, etc

Comment: @JonasAnon Instead of describing the method you at trying to achieve your purpose, describe that purpose. It sounds like you want a proxy server, maybe. If so, you don't need to fiddle with any headers at the TCP layer or below. You'll have two independent, bi-directional connections, with your program shuttling data between them. But I don't know what you want to achieve.

Comment: blocking specific packets from incoming/outgoing is the achievement